# How to set print() to a docx python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a code, that get selenium information and i need to print this information to the docx, but by template. Here i get information with help of print() (to set some part )

---

**Stuyvesant High School**

---

**General Information**

**School Name:**
Stuyvesant High School
**Principal:**
Mr. Eric Contreras
**Principal’s E-mail:**
ECONTRE@SCHOOLS.NYC.GOV
**Type:**
Regular school
**Grade Span:**
9-12
**Address:**
345 Chambers Street, New York, NY 10282

I printing this information in console, but i need print this information to the docx.

Here the part of code, where i print:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import openpyxl
import docx
from docx.shared import Pt

List = []
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('D:\INSPR\Rating_100_schools\Top-100.xlsx')
sheet = wb['RI']
tuple(sheet['A1':'A100']) # Get all cells from A1 to A100.
for rowOfCellObjects in sheet['A1':'A100']:
    for cellObj in rowOfCellObjects:
        List.append(cellObj.value)

School_list_result = []
State = sheet.title

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='D:\chromedriver') #any path

def check_xpath(xpath):
        try:
            element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
            School_list_result.append(element.text)
        except NoSuchElementException:
            School_list_result.append("No data.")
    
def check_text(partial_link_text):
        try:
            element_text = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text(partial_link_text)
            School_list_result.append(element_text.get_attribute("href"))
        except NoSuchElementException:
            School_list_result.append("No data.")
            
def check_click(clicker):
        try:
            element_click = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text(clicker)
            element_click.click()
        except NoSuchElementException:
            print("No click.")
            
def get_url(url, _xpath, send_keys):
    driver.get(url)
    try:
            _element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(_xpath)
            _element.clear()
            driver.implicitly_wait(10)
            _element.send_keys(schools, send_keys)
            _element.send_keys(u'\ue007')
            driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    except NoSuchElementException:
            print("No data.")

for schools in List[98:100]:
    
    #-----------------------------------------GREAT SCHOOLS-------------------------------------------
    get_url("https://www.google.com/", '//*[@id="tsf"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input'," " + State + " greatschools")
    _clicker = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rso"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/a/h3').click()
    
    check_xpath('//*[@id="hero"]/div/div[1]/h1') #School Name
    
    check_xpath('/html/body/div[6]/div[8]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/span[1]') #Principal
    
    check_text('Principal email') #Principal’s E-mail
    
    check_xpath('//*[@id="hero"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]') #Grade Span
    
    check_xpath('//*[@id="hero"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/a/div/span[2]') #Address
    
    check_xpath('/html/body/div[6]/div[8]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/span/a') #Phone
   
    check_text('Website') #Website
   
    check_xpath('//*[@id="hero"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/a') #Associations/Communities
   
    check_xpath('//*[@id="hero"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/a/div[1]/div') #GreatSchools Rating
 
    check_xpath('//*[@id="Students"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]') #Enrollment by Race/Ethnicity
            
    #-----------------------------------------NCES-------------------------------------------
    
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    get_url("https://nces.ed.gov/search/index.asp?q=&btnG=Search#gsc.tab=0", '//*[@id="qt"]', " " + State)
    check_click('Search for Public Schools - ')
    driver.implicitly_wait(10) 
    
    check_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr[7]/td[1]/font[2]') #School type
    
    check_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr[7]/td[3]/font') #Charter
    
    check_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[12]/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody')
    #Enrollment by Gender
    
    check_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[12]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]') #Enrollment by Grade
    
    #-----------------------------------------USNEWS-------------------------------------------
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    url = "https://www.usnews.com/education/best-high-schools/new-york/rankings"
    driver.get(url)
    check_click(schools)
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    
    check_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/p[3]') #U.S.News Rankings
            
    #-----------------------------------------PUBLIC REVIEW-------------------------------------------
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    get_url("https://www.google.com/", '//*[@id="tsf"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input', " " +  State + " publicschoolreview")
    clicker = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('(2020)').click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    
    check_xpath('//*[@id="quick_stats"]/div/div[2]/ul/li[2]/strong') #Total # Students
   
    check_xpath('//*[@id="total_teachers_data_row"]/td[2]') #Full-Time Teachers
        
    check_xpath('//*[@id="quick_stats"]/div/div[2]/ul/li[3]/strong') #Student/Teacher Ratio
        
    #-----------------------------------------PRINT INFOFMATION-------------------------------------------
    
    print("         ---------------------------------------------------------------"+"\n",
          "                              \033[1m", schools,"\033[0m"+"\n",
          "         ---------------------------------------------------------------"+"\n",
          "                              \033[1mGeneral Information\033[0m        "+"\n",
          "\033[1mSchool Name:\n\033[0m",School_list_result[0]+"\n",
          "\033[1mPrincipal:\n\033[0m",School_list_result[1]+"\n",
          "\033[1mPrincipal’s E-mail:\n\033[0m",School_list_result[2]+"\n",
          "\033[1mType:\n\033[0m",School_list_result[10]+"\n",
          "\033[1mGrade Span:\n\033[0m",School_list_result[3]+"\n",
          "\033[1mAddress:\n\033[0m",School_list_result[4]+"\n",
          "\033[1mPhone:\n\033[0m",School_list_result[5]+"\n",
          "\033[1mWebsite:\n\033[0m",School_list_result[6]+"\n",
          "\033[1mAssociations/Communities:\n\033[0m",School_list_result[7]+"\n",
          "\033[1mGreatSchools Summary Rating:\n\033[0m",School_list_result[8]+"\n",
          "\033[1mU.S.News Rankings:\n\033[0m",School_list_result[14]+"\n",
          "                              \033[1mSchool Details\033[0m"+"\n",
          "\033[1mTotal # Students:\n\033[0m",School_list_result[15]+"\n",
          "\033[1mFull-Time Teachers:\n\033[0m",School_list_result[16]+"\n",
          "\033[1mStudent/Teacher Ratio:\n\033[0m",School_list_result[17]+"\n",
          "\033[1mCharter:\n\033[0m",School_list_result[11]+"\n",
          "\033[1mMagnet: \n\033[0m","No""\n",
          "                              \033[1mEnrollment Data\033[0m"+"\n",
          "\033[1mEnrollment by Race/Ethnicity: \n\033[0m",School_list_result[9]+"\n",
          "\033[1mEnrollment by Gender: \n\033[0m",School_list_result[12]+"\n",
          "\033[1mEnrollment by Grade: \n\033[0m",School_list_result[13]+"\n",
          ()
         )
    
    
    print()
    
    School_list_result.clear()
```

What i need: print this result not into console by template, but into a docx by template.
And one more: if you know how to not using indexing (like: ***School_list_result[0]***), please tell me.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219197/discussion-on-question-by-kate-sls-how-to-set-print-to-a-docx-python).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are on a windows operating system just as I do, and know how to download python packages:

1. Install `docx` and `python-docx` modules (they are different, make sure you have installed both)
2. use the following code:

```
School_list_result = [
    "Stuyvesant High School",
    "Mr. Eric Contreras",
    "ECONTRE@SCHOOLS.NYC.GOV",
    "Regular school",
    "9-12",
    "345 Chambers Street, New York, NY 10282",
]

headers = [
    "School Name: ",
    "Principal: ",
    "Principal's Email: ",
    "Type: ",
    "Grade Span: ",
    "Address: ",
]


def print_into_one_doc():
    import os
    from docx import Document
    from docx.shared import RGBColor
    from docx.shared import Pt
    from docx.enum.text import WD_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT

    # after you create a docx file, make sure you double click to open it, write some stuff, press ctrl + s, delete what you have written, press ctrl + s, close the document
    # delete what you have written. Otherwise python-docx reports a Package Not Find Error. 
    p = input('hold shift key right click, copy and paste the file path of docx here: ')
    if p[0] == '"' or p[0] == "'":
        # validate path
        p = p[1:-1]
    p = os.path.abspath(p)
    doc = Document(p)
    h = doc.add_paragraph()
    # make title align to center
    h.paragraph_format.alignment = WD_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT.CENTER
    r = h.add_run(School_list_result[0])
    # set title color
    r.font.color.rgb = RGBColor(54, 95, 145)
    # set title size
    r.font.size = Pt(36)
    doc.add_paragraph('\n')
    su = doc.add_paragraph()
    ru = su.add_run('General Information')
    ru.font.size = Pt(30)
    for i, d in enumerate(headers):
        sp = doc.add_paragraph()
        rp = sp.add_run(headers[i])
        rp.bold = True
        rp.font.size = Pt(23)
        sm = doc.add_paragraph()
        rm = sm.add_run(School_list_result[i])
        rm.font.size = Pt(22)
        rm.italic = True
    doc.add_page_break()
    doc.save(p)


print_into_one_doc()
```

3. If you have a list, which contains `School_list_result`, iterate it through, here is an example:

```
List_of_school_list_result = [
    [
        "Stuyvesant High School",
        "Mr. Eric Contreras",
        "ECONTRE@SCHOOLS.NYC.GOV",
        "Regular school",
        "9-12",
        "345 Chambers Street, New York, NY 10282",
    ],
    [
        "Great Lake College",
        "Mr. Jason Madunic",
        "MADUNIC@SCHOOLS.VIC.GOV",
        "Public school",
        "6-12",
        "167A High Street, Melbourne, VIC 3228",
    ],
]

headers = [
    "School Name: ",
    "Principal: ",
    "Principal's Email: ",
    "Type: ",
    "Grade Span: ",
    "Address: ",
]


def print_all_into_one_doc():
    import os
    from docx import Document
    from docx.shared import RGBColor
    from docx.shared import Pt
    from docx.enum.text import WD_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT

    # after you create a new docx file, double click to open it, write some stuff, press ctrl + s, delete what you have written, press ctrl + s, close the document
    # Otherwise python-docx reports a Package Note Find Error. 
    p = input('hold shift key right click, copy and paste the file path of docx here: ')
    if p[0] == '"' or p[0] == "'":
        # validate path
        p = p[1:-1]
    p = os.path.abspath(p)
    doc = Document(p)
    # iterate List of all school
    for j in List_of_school_list_result:
        h = doc.add_paragraph()
        # make title align to center
        h.paragraph_format.alignment = WD_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT.CENTER
        r = h.add_run(j[0])
        # set title color: you can adjust any color of title here 
        r.font.color.rgb = RGBColor(54, 95, 145)
        # set title size
        r.font.size = Pt(36)
        doc.add_paragraph('\n')
        su = doc.add_paragraph()
        ru = su.add_run('General Information')
        ru.font.size = Pt(30)
        for i, d in enumerate(headers):
            sp = doc.add_paragraph()
            rp = sp.add_run(headers[i])
            rp.bold = True
            rp.font.size = Pt(23)
            sm = doc.add_paragraph()
            rm = sm.add_run(j[i])
            rm.font.size = Pt(22)
            rm.italic = True
        doc.add_page_break()
    doc.save(p)


print_all_into_one_doc()
```

Let's make it simple, what you need to do is:

1. create a list named `List_of_school_list_result`, dump your data in, each of them should be one single record of a certain school.
2. in any location, create a new docx file, double click to open it, write some stuff, press ctrl + s, delete what you have written, press ctrl + s, close the document.
3. go to the directory where your docx file is, hold on shift, right click, copy as path.
4. make sure `docx` and `python-docx` are installed, run the code, when you are asked to input the path, paste it in from your clipboard. (Please make sure you use an absolute path, which is a full directory with root c, a relative path may not work).

PS: the reason that you have to open the docx file after create, is that Microsoft Word 2005+ docx file have 3 modes. first, if it's brand new after creation, it's in binary format. second, if we open it to edit, it generates a $cache.docx file as hidden into same level directory to ensure performance and secure data just in case of crash. third, if it's edited and saved, the format will be turned into XML, which is EDITABLE using `python-docx` module.

PS: the Result class below provides a clear way for creating `List_of_school_list_result`:

```
class Result:
    def __init__(self, length):
        self.l = length
        self.res = []
        self.col = []

    def push(self, string):
        self.col.append(string)
        if(len(self.col) == self.l):
            self.res.append(self.col)
            self.col = []

    def publish(self):
        return self.res


r = Result(6) # pass in the length of the headers, then all you need, is to call `r.push()` over and over again. after that, assign it to `List_of_school_list_result`
r.push('school name 1')
r.push('principal name 1')
r.push('principal email 1')
r.push('school type 1')
r.push('grad span 1')
r.push('address 1')

r.push('school name 2')
r.push('principal name 2')
r.push('principal email 2')
r.push('school type 2')
r.push('grad span 2')
r.push('address 2')
List_of_school_list_result = r.publish()
```

Complete version of code:

```
headers = [
    "School Name: ",
    "Principal: ",
    "Principal's Email: ",
    "Type: ",
    "Grade Span: ",
    "Address: ",
]

class Result:
    def __init__(self, length):
        self.l = length
        self.res = []
        self.col = []

    def push(self, string):
        self.col.append(string)
        if(len(self.col) == self.l):
            self.res.append(self.col)
            self.col = []

    def publish(self):
        return self.res


r = Result(len(headers))

# call r.push() over and over again, until all the string data is passed in.

''' for example
r.push('school name 1')
r.push('principal name 1')
r.push('principal email 1')
r.push('school type 1')
r.push('grad span 1')
r.push('address 1')

r.push('school name 2')
r.push('principal name 2')
r.push('principal email 2')
r.push('school type 2')
r.push('grad span 2')
r.push('address 2')
'''

List_of_school_list_result = r.publish()


def print_all_into_one_doc():
    import os
    from docx import Document
    from docx.shared import RGBColor
    from docx.shared import Pt
    from docx.enum.text import WD_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT

    # after you create a new docx file, double click to open it, write some stuff, press ctrl + s, delete what you have written, press ctrl + s, close the document
    # Otherwise python-docx reports a Package Note Find Error. 
    p = input('hold shift key right click, copy and paste the file path of docx here: ')
    if p[0] == '"' or p[0] == "'":
        # validate path
        p = p[1:-1]
    p = os.path.abspath(p)
    doc = Document(p)
    # iterate List of all school
    for j in List_of_school_list_result:
        h = doc.add_paragraph()
        # make title align to center
        h.paragraph_format.alignment = WD_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT.CENTER
        r = h.add_run(j[0])
        # set title color: you can adjust any color of title here 
        r.font.color.rgb = RGBColor(54, 95, 145)
        # set title size
        r.font.size = Pt(36)
        doc.add_paragraph('\n')
        su = doc.add_paragraph()
        ru = su.add_run('General Information')
        ru.font.size = Pt(30)
        for i, d in enumerate(headers):
            sp = doc.add_paragraph()
            rp = sp.add_run(headers[i])
            rp.bold = True
            rp.font.size = Pt(23)
            sm = doc.add_paragraph()
            rm = sm.add_run(j[i])
            rm.font.size = Pt(22)
            rm.italic = True
        doc.add_page_break()
    doc.save(p)


print_all_into_one_doc()
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion or debugging sessions; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219196/discussion-on-answer-by-weilory-how-to-set-print-to-a-docx-python). Please make sure to [edit] all relevant information into the answer.